# MySQL Workbench: Error When Attempting Schema Export "global name "self" is not defined"

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

This comes up as soon as Export is clicked in MySQL Workbench.  Error log entry:

```
18:19:12 [ERR][wb_admin_main.py:tab_changed:211]: Unhandled exception in Admin for <wb_admin_export.WbAdminExport; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'mforms::Box *' at 0x10d767630

: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Resources/plugins/wb_admin_main.py", line 208, in tab_changed
    panel.page_activated()
  File "/Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Resources/plugins/wb_admin_export.py", line 2255, in page_activated
    self.create_ui()
  File "/Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Resources/plugins/wb_admin_export.py", line 2308, in create_ui
    self.options_tab = WbAdminExportOptionsTab(self.ctrl_be.target_version, self.export_tab.mysqldump_defaults)
  File "/Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Resources/plugins/wb_admin_export.py", line 1997, in __init__
    mysqldump_version = get_mysqldump_version()
  File "/Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Resources/plugins/wb_admin_export.py", line 113, in get_mysqldump_version
    self.print_log_message("Error retrieving version from %s:\n%s (exit %s)"%(path, output, rc))
NameError: global name 'self' is not defined
```

Comment: If my edit incorrectly changed your error log, please change it back.

Answer (score -1):

Reinstalling Workbench solved the problem.